# C++: Inserting objects in a Binary Search Tree using recursion

Tags: c++, templates, recursion, insert, binary-search-tree

When I attempt to add files to this tree it will only add as a child of the root of the tree.
The comparison operator is correctly overloaded (tested).

Can anyone see anything obviously wrong with my code?

```
template <typename Item>
void BTtree<Item>::addNode(const Item& newItem)
{
    BTnode<Item> *newNode = new BTnode<Item>(newItem);
    insert(newNode, root_ptr);
}   

template <typename Item>
void BTtree<Item>::insert(BTnode<Item> *newNode, BTnode<Item> *root)
{               
    if(root == NULL)
    {
        root = newNode;
        std::cout << "Flight added: ";
        std::cout << *root << std::endl;
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        if(newNode < root )
        {
            std::cout << "Adding "<<*newNode<< " left child of " << *root << std::endl;
            insert(newNode, root->left() );
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Adding "<<*newNode<<" right child of " << *root << std::endl;
            insert(newNode, root->right());
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: Supplying code for overloaded operators

```
template <typename Item>
bool BTnode<Item>::operator < (const BTnode<Item>& other)
{
    return ( *data < other.data );
}
```

And for the objects I am using

```
const bool Flight::operator < (const Flight& other) const
{
return ( (arrivalTimeHours < other.arrivalTimeHours) || 
         (arrivalTimeHours == other.arrivalTimeHours &&
          arrivalTimeMinutes < other.arrivalTimeMinutes)
);
```

Comment: `newNode < root` compares two pointers. What you want is compare two `BTnode<Item>`s. Is the pointer comparison overloaded appropriately?

Comment: please attach your overloaded operator codes

Comment: Better yet, provide a [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org).

Comment: Oswald, you are right, I didn't notice that. I was originally comparing the Items but I have rewritten it after I changed the function to take two nodes as parameters
But even when comparing the items it does the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `root->left() == NULL`, then after `insert(newNode, root->left() )`, the condition `root->left() == NULL` still holds, because the assignement `root = newNode` does not have any effect on the caller.

Your signature

```
void BTtree<Item>::insert(BTnode<Item> *newNode, BTnode<Item> *root)
```

is *not* call-by-reference. It's call-by-value. It's just that the value happens to be of a pointer type.

I suggest the following approach:

- Move the recursion into the `BTnode` class
- The recursive function takes a `const Item&` as argument
- If the recursive function should enter a branch where there is none, it creates the `BTnode` from the `Item` and sets the appropriate member variable to the newly created `BTnode`.
- Make sure that the destructor of the `BTnode` destroys both its children.
- Disallow copying or write appropriate copy constuctor and copy assignment operator (see [Rule of Three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C++_programming%29)).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.
If root->left()==NULL, and I pass it as a parameter, then on the recurring function the first if statement will be true, and it will set that root to the hewNode?

Comment: Put `std::cout << root->left() << ':' << root->right();` before and after each `insert` call and see what happens.

Comment: It's not printing any correct flights at all.. hmm. In fact all of them are empty (default constructor) valus for Flight.
Thanks for your help Oswald, I'm going to dig deeper